# Redis increment several fields in several hsets

Tags: redis, jedis

I have data of several users in redis e.g.

hset - user111; field - dayssincelogin .....

I want to periodically update dayssincelogin for all users, one way to do it is

```
KEYS user*
HINCRBY ${key from above} dayssincelogin 1
```

Is it possible to do this in a single call? If not what's the most optimal way? **I'm using using redis cluster and java client.**

Comment: What do you mean by

> I'm using a redis **cluster**

Comment: @ItamarHaber As you mention below .. Redis 3 cluster with sharding

Answer (score 6):

You can't do multiple increments in one command but you can bulk your commands together for performance gains.

Use Redis Pipe-lining or Scripting.

<strike>In Jedis I dont thing LUA is supported (If someone could answer that :) )</strike>

As @mp911de suggested; Use [Exec](https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/wiki/AdvancedUsage) for LUA Scripting 
and you can also use pipelining to execute your bulk methods faster.

Have a [Pipelining readup here](http://redis.io/topics/pipelining) for more information

And here is the [sample code to use Jedis Pipelining](https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/blob/411f4e76f1017ec7c97e74ecb7f84f36562fcc21/src/test/java/redis/clients/jedis/tests/PipeliningTest.java).

```
Pipeline p = jedis.pipelined();
p.multi();
Response<Long> r1 = p.hincrBy("a", "f1", -1);
Response<Long> r2 = p.hincrBy("a", "f1", -2);
Response<List<Object>> r3 = p.exec();
List<Object> result = p.syncAndReturnAll();
```

**Edit: Redis allows multi key operations only when they are present in the same shard. You should arrange your keys in such a way to ensure data affinity. like `key1.{foo}` and `key5678.{foo}` will reside in the same server**

Comment: Lua scripts can be executed using the `exec()` method in jedis.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. Editing the answer

Comment: Note that the OP is using a cluster - if it is a sharded setup (v3), all keys need to be in the same slot for a MULTI it Lua to work.

Comment: Then Pipelining is the best way to go ?

Comment: Same considerations apply to pipelining I'm afraid.

Comment: While pipelining is good for single node, it does not work for cluster. So can't accept the answer. Please edit.